# T-SQL :: generate random Swiss National Identification Number (AHV/AVS)

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I woul like to generate random Swiss National Identification Number (AHV/AVS).

I found a website that [can do that](https://teaddict.net/swiss-ssn.html) and if I look at the source code of the same page I can alos see the `JavaScript` [code that can generate it](https://unpkg.com/swiss-ssn@1.0.1/dist/swiss-ssn.min.js).

The numbers are generated following this pattern:

[image]

1. `756`: is the prefix number, it never changes
2. `1234`: is a random number
3. `5678`: is a random number
4. `9`: is a random number
5. `7`: is the **control number** that is generated by this calculation:

   - Starting at the first number, take every other number and sum them: `7 + 6 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8` = `33`
   - Starting at the drcond number, take every other number and sum them: `5 + 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9` = `30`
   - Then multiply the second number `x 3` and sum the first number: `33 + (30 x 3)` = `123`
   - Now make `10` minus the modulo of that number: `10-(123%10)` = `10-3` = `7`

> ===> And this is how we finally have obtained `7` which is the last number <===

I have created a SQL command that can generate the random number I need:

```
SELECT CONCAT('756.', 
FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(9999-1000+1)+1000) , '.',
FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(9999-1000+1)+1000) , '.',
ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10
-- How to select one number out of two? 
)
```

This code generates all random numbers that I need but I'm missing how to select one number out of two.

I don't know if `T-SQL` can parse numbers and select one out of two.

Comment: *"starting from the fisrt number take one number out of two and sum them: 7 + 6 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 33"* Huh? Take one number and sum it? That would be the number itself. `SUM(7) = 7` If you take one number, why does the expression have 6 numbers? I don't follow that logic.

Comment: Sorry, that is my poor english... you have to sum `first, third, fifth, seventh, nineth, eleven`

Comment: So do you mean something like "Starting at the first number, take every other number (1st, 3rd, 5th, etc) and `SUM` them."

Comment: and then `second, forth, sixth, eight, ten, twelve`

Comment: YES @Larnu, take every other number is what I was looking for, I'm going to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation uses integer calculations instead of substring to get digits.

**Note:** I have added %10 to the final result of check digit calculation to convert 10 -> 0.

```
-- Format Number
SELECT *, CAST( Prefix AS CHAR( 3 )) + '.' + CAST( Rnd1 AS CHAR( 4 )) + '.' + CAST( Rnd2 AS CHAR( 4 )) + '.' + CAST( Rnd3 AS CHAR( 1 )) + CAST( CheckDigit AS CHAR( 1 )) AS FinalNum
FROM(
    -- Step 2: calculate check digit. NOTE: I apply %10 to the result to convert 10 to 0
    SELECT *, ( 10 - (( OddDigits + ( EvenDigits ) * 3 ) % 10 )) % 10 AS CheckDigit
    FROM 
        -- Step 2: calculate Odd / Even digit sum. Note that prefix is hardcoded to 756
        ( SELECT Prefix, Rnd1, Rnd2, Rnd3,
            7 + 6 + (( Rnd1 % 1000 ) / 100 ) + ( Rnd1 % 10 ) + (( Rnd2 % 1000 ) / 100 ) + ( Rnd2 % 10 ) AS OddDigits,
            5 + ( Rnd1 / 1000 ) + (( Rnd1 % 100 ) / 10 ) + ( Rnd2 / 1000 ) + (( Rnd2 % 100 ) / 10 ) + Rnd3 AS EvenDigits
        FROM
            -- Step 1: initial random values. Note that prefix is hardcoded to 756
            ( VALUES( 756,
                CAST( FLOOR( RAND( CHECKSUM( NEWID())) * ( 9999 - 1000 ) + 1000 ) AS INT ),
                CAST( FLOOR( RAND( CHECKSUM( NEWID())) * ( 9999 - 1000 ) + 1000 ) AS INT ),
                ABS( CHECKSUM( NEWID())) % 10 ),
                -- Your original example. Should be removed in production code
                (756, 1234, 5678, 9))   AS RndNum( Prefix, Rnd1, Rnd2, Rnd3 )
        ) AS CtrlDigitCalculation
    ) AS FormattedNumber
```

**Result**

```
Prefix      Rnd1        Rnd2        Rnd3        OddDigits   EvenDigits  CheckDigit  FinalNum
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
756         3826        4185        8           34          34          9           756.8002.7335.52
756         1234        5678        9           33          30          7           756.1234.5678.97
```

**Update**

Checked the return value of random number generator expression and found that it can return a 5 digit value i.e. 10000.

```
SELECT CAST( FLOOR( CAST( 1.0 AS FLOAT ) * ( 9999 - 1000 + 1 ) + 1000 ) AS INT )
-- Result: 10000
```

To fix it you need to remove "+ 1":

```
SELECT CAST( FLOOR( CAST( 1.0 AS FLOAT ) * ( 9999 - 1000 ) + 1000 ) AS INT )
-- Result: 9999
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice too, thank you Alex. I like your approach, generating random number one at the time.

Comment: I don't get why it creates 2 rows instead of 1

Comment: I have used a value from your original example: "(756, 1234, 5678, 9)". You can remove it.

Comment: Do _random_ numbers include values less than 1000? `CAST( FLOOR( RAND( CHECKSUM( NEWID())) * ( 9999 - 1000 + 1 ) + 1000 ) AS INT )` doesn't generate them.

Comment: `RAND` function returns numbers between 0 and 1. The formula is ( RND( 0 to 1 ) * 9000 ) + 1000. The smallest number (when RND is 0) will be 1000. The largest (just checked can be 1000). Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, your current logic is flawed, you get a random number between 0 and 9999, *however* you don't make that value fixed width. As a result, if your random numbers were `7`, `9`, and `2`, you'd end up with `792` *not* `00700090002`. You need to add the leading zeros. I do this with `CONCAT` and `RIGHT`.

Next I move the expression into the `FROM` so that it's materialised and easily usable. Then we can use `SUBSTRING` and `CONVERT` to get the 2 parts of your number and `SUM` them, and then finally apply the final logic. I then inject the periods into the string.

```sql
SELECT V.NIN,
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CONCAT(V.NIN,10 - ((Odds + (Evens * 3)) % 10)),12,0,'.'),8,0,'.'),4,0,'.')
FROM (VALUES(CONCAT(RIGHT(CONCAT('000','756'),3), 
                    RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(9999-1000+1)+1000)),4),
                    RIGHT(CONCAT('0000',FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(9999-1000+1)+1000)),4),
                    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%10)),
            ('756123456789'))V(NIN)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,1,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,3,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,5,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,7,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,9,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,11,1)),
                         CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,2,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,4,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,6,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,8,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,10,1)) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(V.NIN,12,1))))I(Odds,Evens)
```

Honestly, however, I would suggest that this is probably something for your application, not SQL.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu, I will use this to anonymize a database. I need to anonymize a column that contains AVS numbers.

Comment: Note that, the last digit calculation can sometimes generate "10". While this is not stated in your rules I believe you need to %10 the final result to get 10 converted to 0.

Comment: Larnu, re "
Firstly, your current logic is flawed, you get a random number between 0 and 9999, however you don't make that value fixed width." - you are mistaken. The formula he uses is RND * (9999-1000+1)+1000), so the smallest number that can be returned is 1000

Answer (score 2):

Another method to generate a random SNIN with a control number.

The trick used is a cross apply, with number values to calculate the sums of  odds and evens.

```
select concat(code, ctrl) as SNIN
from (values
  (concat('756','.', right(format(rand()*100000,'0000'),4)
               ,'.', right(format(rand()*100000,'0000'),4)
               ,'.', right(format(rand()*100,'0'),1))) 
, ('756.1234.5678.9')
, ('756.1917.1051.7')
) v(code)
cross apply (
  select (10-(sum(odds)+(3*sum(evens)))%10)%10 as ctrl
  from (
    select 
      cast(substring(code_nr,(n*2)+1,1) as int) as odds
    , cast(substring(code_nr,(n+1)*2,1) as int) as evens
    from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as nums(n)
    cross join (select replace(code,'.','')) as code(code_nr)
  ) q
) ca;
```

| SNIN |
| --- |
| 756.9357.6870.03 |
| 756.1234.5678.97 |
| 756.1917.1051.70 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f63aab4ea42f2c8af07b0b00a61fc648)*

Comment: Thank you for the effort @LukStorms but it returns me 3 digit numbers at the end: https://snipboard.io/sBN6va.jpg

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Indeed, it needed an extra modulus. Since 10-0=10. Thanks.